# Relationship issue on neo4j.ogm using spring boot application

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

In my project i am using org.neo4j.ogm with spring boot. While i am trying to create a relationship using @RelationshipEntity means it will created successfully. But it does not support multiple to one relation.

Here i am creating relationship for Blueprint to ScTaxonomy at the relationship on RELATED_TO_ScTaxonomy. And i want to add relationship properties for catalogueBlueprint class.

I mean Blueprint-(RELATED_TO_ScTaxonomy)-ScTaxonomy with catalogueBlueprint class values was saved on RELATED_TO_ScTaxonomy.

once i restart the service then i'll create a new connection means already created relations are lost and only the newly created relations only saved.

I am using the query for

```html
package nuclei.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

public class Blueprint extends Entity {

 private String blueprint;
 private String onIaas;
 private String script;

 private String isDeleted;

 @Relationship(type = "iaaSTemplate", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
 IaaSTemplate iaaSTemplate;

 @Relationship(type = "iaasParameters")
 List<IaasParameters> iaasParameters;

 @Relationship(type = "tasks")
 List<Tasks> tasks;

 @Relationship(type = "RELATED_TO_ScTaxonomy")
 @JsonIgnore
    public List<CatalogueBlueprint> relations;
 
 
 public Blueprint() {
  iaaSTemplate = new IaaSTemplate();
  iaasParameters = new ArrayList<IaasParameters>();
  tasks = new ArrayList<Tasks>();
  relations = new ArrayList<CatalogueBlueprint>();
 }
 
  public void addRelation(ScTaxonomy scTaxonomyRelation,CatalogueBlueprint catalogueBlueprint) {
   catalogueBlueprint.blueprintRelation = this;
   catalogueBlueprint.scTaxonomyRelation = scTaxonomyRelation;
   
   relations.add(catalogueBlueprint);
 /*  relations.setCatalogueBlueprintId(catalogueBlueprint.getCatalogueBlueprintId());
   relations.setOnIaas(catalogueBlueprint.getOnIaas());
   relations.setScript(catalogueBlueprint.getScript());
   relations.setX_axis(catalogueBlueprint.getX_axis());
   relations.setY_axis(catalogueBlueprint.getY_axis());
   relations.setStep(catalogueBlueprint.getStep());
   relations.setIsDeleted(catalogueBlueprint.getIsDeleted());*/
   
      scTaxonomyRelation.relations.add(catalogueBlueprint);
     }

 public Blueprint(String blueprint, String onIaas, String script,
   String isDeleted) {
  this.blueprint = blueprint;
  this.onIaas = onIaas;
  this.script = script;
  this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
 }

 public String getBlueprint() {
  return blueprint;
 }

 public void setBlueprint(String blueprint) {
  this.blueprint = blueprint;
 }

 public String getOnIaas() {
  return onIaas;
 }

 public void setOnIaas(String onIaas) {
  this.onIaas = onIaas;
 }

 public String getScript() {
  return script;
 }

 public void setScript(String script) {
  this.script = script;
 }

 public String getIsDeleted() {
  return isDeleted;
 }

 public void setIsDeleted(String isDeleted) {
  this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
 }

 public List<IaasParameters> getIaasParameters() {
  return iaasParameters;
 }

 public void setIaasParameters(List<IaasParameters> iaasParameters) {
  this.iaasParameters = iaasParameters;
 }

 public List<Tasks> getTasks() {
  return tasks;
 }

 public void setTasks(List<Tasks> tasks) {
  this.tasks = tasks;
 }

 public IaaSTemplate getIaaSTemplate() {
  return iaaSTemplate;
 }

 public void setIaaSTemplate(IaaSTemplate iaaSTemplate) {
  this.iaaSTemplate = iaaSTemplate;
 }

 public List<CatalogueBlueprint> getRelations() {
  return relations;
 }

 public void setRelations(List<CatalogueBlueprint> relations) {
  this.relations = relations;
 }

}
```

```html
/**
 * 
 */
package nuclei.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

/**
 * @author Karthikeyan
 *
 */

public class ScTaxonomy extends Entity {

 private String taxName; 
 private String description;
 private String isDeleted;
 private String step;
 private String serviceCatalogueStep; 
 private String x_axis;
 private String y_axis;

 @Relationship(type = "RELATED_TO_ScTaxonomy", direction = "INCOMING")
    public List<CatalogueBlueprint> relations;
 
 public ScTaxonomy() {
  relations = new ArrayList<>(); 
 }

 public ScTaxonomy(String taxName, String description, String isDeleted,String step,String serviceCatalogueStep,
   String x_axis,String y_axis) {
  this.taxName=taxName;
  this.description = description;  
  this.isDeleted = isDeleted; 
  this.step=step;
  this.serviceCatalogueStep=serviceCatalogueStep;
  this.x_axis=x_axis;
  this.y_axis=y_axis;
 }

 public String getTaxName() {
  return taxName;
 }

 public void setTaxName(String taxName) {
  this.taxName = taxName;
 }

 public String getDescription() {
  return description;
 }

 public void setDescription(String description) {
  this.description = description;
 }

 public String getIsDeleted() {
  return isDeleted;
 }

 public void setIsDeleted(String isDeleted) {
  this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
 }

 public String getStep() {
  return step;
 }

 public void setStep(String step) {
  this.step = step;
 }

 public String getServiceCatalogueStep() {
  return serviceCatalogueStep;
 }

 public void setServiceCatalogueStep(String serviceCatalogueStep) {
  this.serviceCatalogueStep = serviceCatalogueStep;
 }

 public String getX_axis() {
  return x_axis;
 }

 public void setX_axis(String x_axis) {
  this.x_axis = x_axis;
 }

 public String getY_axis() {
  return y_axis;
 }

 public void setY_axis(String y_axis) {
  this.y_axis = y_axis;
 }

 public List<CatalogueBlueprint> getRelations() {
  return relations;
 }

 public void setRelations(List<CatalogueBlueprint> relations) {
  this.relations = relations;
 } 
  
}
```

```html
package nuclei.domain;

import java.util.List;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.EndNode;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.RelationshipEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.StartNode;

@RelationshipEntity(type="catalogueBlueprint")
public class CatalogueBlueprint extends Entity {

 private long catalogueBlueprintId;
 private String onIaas;
 private String script;
 private String x_axis;
 private String y_axis;
 private String step;
 private String isDeleted;

 @StartNode
    public  Blueprint blueprintRelation;
 
 @EndNode
 public ScTaxonomy scTaxonomyRelation;
 
 public CatalogueBlueprint() {
 
 }

 public CatalogueBlueprint(ScTaxonomy to,Blueprint from, String onIaas, String script,long catalogueBlueprintId,
   String isDeleted,String x_axis,String y_axis,String step) {
  
  this.scTaxonomyRelation=to;
  this.blueprintRelation=from;
  this.onIaas = onIaas;
  this.script = script;
  this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
  this.x_axis=x_axis;
  this.y_axis=y_axis;
  this.step=step;
  this.catalogueBlueprintId=catalogueBlueprintId;
 }

 public long getCatalogueBlueprintId() {
  return catalogueBlueprintId;
 }

 public void setCatalogueBlueprintId(long catalogueBlueprintId) {
  this.catalogueBlueprintId = catalogueBlueprintId;
 }

 public String getOnIaas() {
  return onIaas;
 }

 public void setOnIaas(String onIaas) {
  this.onIaas = onIaas;
 }

 public String getScript() {
  return script;
 }

 public void setScript(String script) {
  this.script = script;
 }

 public String getX_axis() {
  return x_axis;
 }

 public void setX_axis(String x_axis) {
  this.x_axis = x_axis;
 }

 public String getY_axis() {
  return y_axis;
 }

 public void setY_axis(String y_axis) {
  this.y_axis = y_axis;
 }

 public String getStep() {
  return step;
 }

 public void setStep(String step) {
  this.step = step;
 }

 public String getIsDeleted() {
  return isDeleted;
 }

 public void setIsDeleted(String isDeleted) {
  this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
 }

 public ScTaxonomy getScTaxonomyRelation() {
  return scTaxonomyRelation;
 }

 public void setScTaxonomyRelation(ScTaxonomy scTaxonomyRelation) {
  this.scTaxonomyRelation = scTaxonomyRelation;
 }

 public Blueprint getBlueprintRelation() {
  return blueprintRelation;
 }

 public void setBlueprintRelation(Blueprint blueprintRelation) {
  this.blueprintRelation = blueprintRelation;
 }

}
```

```html
/**
 * 
 */
package nuclei.controller;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import nuclei.domain.CatalogueBlueprint;
import nuclei.domain.IaaSTemplate;
import nuclei.domain.IaasParameters;
import nuclei.domain.ScTaxonomy;
import nuclei.domain.Tasks;
import nuclei.domain.Blueprint;
import nuclei.response.BlueprintMessage;
import nuclei.response.BlueprintsMessage;
import nuclei.response.CatalogueBlueprintMessage;
import nuclei.response.ResponseStatus;
import nuclei.response.ResponseStatusCode;
import nuclei.service.CatalogueBlueprintService;
import nuclei.service.MainService;
import nuclei.service.BlueprintService;
import nuclei.service.ScTaxonomyService;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

/**
 * @author Karthikeyan
 *
 */

// @RestController
@Controller
public class BlueprintController extends MainController<Blueprint> {

 @Autowired
 private CatalogueBlueprintService catalogueBlueprintService;
 
 @Autowired
 private ScTaxonomyService scTaxonomyService;
 
 @Autowired
 private BlueprintService blueprintService;


 //create scTaxonomy relation
  @RequestMapping(value = "/createScTaxonomyRelation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody BlueprintMessage relationTest(
    @FormDataParam("ScTaxonomyId") String ScTaxonomyId,
    @FormDataParam("blueprintId") String blueprintId,
    @FormDataParam("catalogueBlueprintId") String catalogueBlueprintId,  
    @FormDataParam("onIaas") String onIaas,
    @FormDataParam("script") String script,
    @FormDataParam("step") String step,   
    @FormDataParam("x_axis") String x_axis,
    @FormDataParam("y_axis") String y_axis,
    final HttpServletResponse response) {
   
   ResponseStatus status = null;
   Long blueptId = Long.parseLong(blueprintId);
   Long taxonomyId = Long.parseLong(ScTaxonomyId); 
   List<CatalogueBlueprint> catalogueBPList =  new ArrayList<CatalogueBlueprint>();
   CatalogueBlueprint catalogueBP=new CatalogueBlueprint();
   Blueprint blueprint=null;  
   ScTaxonomy taxonomy = null;
   try {
    
    Long catalogueID=Long.parseLong(catalogueBlueprintId);
    taxonomy = scTaxonomyService.find(taxonomyId);
         
    blueprint=blueprintService.find(blueptId);
    
    catalogueBP.setBlueprintRelation(blueprint);
    catalogueBP.setScTaxonomyRelation(taxonomy);
    
    catalogueBP.setOnIaas(onIaas);
    catalogueBP.setCatalogueBlueprintId(catalogueID);
    catalogueBP.setScript(script); 
    catalogueBP.setStep(step);   
    catalogueBP.setX_axis(x_axis);
    catalogueBP.setY_axis(y_axis);
    catalogueBP.setIsDeleted("0");  
    
    catalogueBPList.add(catalogueBP);     
      
    blueprint.addRelation(taxonomy, catalogueBP);
    
    super.create(blueprint);
    //super.update(blueptId, blueprint);
   
    status = new ResponseStatus(ResponseStatusCode.STATUS_OK, "SUCCESS");
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return new BlueprintMessage(status, blueprint);
  }

 @Override
 public MainService<Blueprint> getService() {
  return blueprintService;
 }

 
}
```

Comment: that's a lot of code to digest. Can you please post only the relevant secionts

Comment: How could i use RelationshipEntity for neo4j.ogm with spring boot application.
using StartNode and EndNode

Comment: I'm assuming you've managed to upgrade to 4.0.0.RC2? There were issues with relationship entities in previous versions.

Comment: I am trying that one also once i upgrade the version into 4.0.0.RC2 means it shows some error while i am run the project.

Comment: The error was "
java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()"

Comment: Which version of spring-data-commons is pulled in (with dependency:tree).

Comment: Specifically I am not using anyone.. But SDN 4.0.0.RC2 have the spring-data-commons. So I'm using that only.

Comment: Some other dependency could have pulled it in too. Please check with mvn dependency:tree

Comment: Now i am removed all the dependencies and add updated versions for all the dependency then the error was not showing and the application was running successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am removed all the dependencies and add updated versions for all the dependency then the error was not showing and the application was running successfully.